# Op-Amp circuit that works as integrator and differentiator

Tags: operational-amplifier, differential-amplifier, integrator

> Determine the conditions for the circuit to act as a differentiator and integrator.
>
> Determine Avlc for both situations.
>
> C = 100nF
>
> R = 1k ohm

The closed loop gain for this circuit is:

$$ A_{vLC} = \frac{1}{RC}*\frac{\omega}{\omega^2+(\frac{1}{RC})^2}$$

[image: circuit]

[image]

The Bode plotter gives me -20db (simulation) for both situations, but when I replace the values:

[image]

Shouldn't it give me -20db? Do I need to do a conversion or what?

Answer (score 0):

Voltage gain is like constant multiplier but dB is in log scale.
By simply convert 10/101 to dB we got -20 dB correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The amplifier or integrator, also a low pass filter, provides an output signal proportional to the time integral of the input signal. Only at 0dB does it provide a signal with the same amplitude of the input one. For frequencies lower than 1/(RfC) it behaves like an inverting amplifier. See explanatory photos:

[image]
The derivator or high pass filter has a complementary behavior:
[image]
Regarding the requested case:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The shown circuit will never "*act as a differentiator and integrator*".
However, within some specific frequency regions it can approach the function of an integrator resp. differentiator.
Therefore, the question can only be answered when the accuracy (resp. the deviation from the ideal function) is specified,